# List items through view based on list of terms from field

Tags: views

I have started making all my content and now I just need to figure out one more thing and I have played around but can't get anything to work without it being overly complicated and I'm sure there is a much simpler way.

I have a "Lesson" content type which right now has the fields:

- Title
- Body
- Vocabulary

I also have a "Dictionary" content type which has the fields:

- Title
- English
- Audio
- Part of Speech

I manually create an HTML table of the vocabulary learned in the lesson in the Vocabulary Field which I manually link to it's dictionary content entry.

I figured there has to be a better/smarter way to do this through a view or maybe another module. Is there a way to make a list of words in a "Lesson Node" and have a view pull those words from "Dictionary" in a view?

Ultimately this is what I would want displayed:

---

Navigation Bar

---

Lesson Node Title

Lesson Node Body text will go here explaining the lessons and everything else that is in the body of the "Lesson" content type

---

(This section is the words pulled from the "Dictionary" which is based on the words used in the Lesson)

--------------|--------------|------------|

Foriegn Word  | English Word |   Audio    |

--------------|--------------|------------|

Foriegn Word  | English Word |   Audio    |

--------------|--------------|------------|

Foriegn Word  | English Word |   Audio    |

--------------|--------------|------------|

Foriegn Word  | English Word |   Audio    |

--------------|--------------|------------|

So let's say that "Lesson one" teaches us the words cat, dog, mouse, house. I want only those entries from the "Dictionary" to be displayed underneath the body of "Lesson one"

Comment: did you get it to work?

Comment: I swear Drupal just hates me, I copied the content types, fields, displays, filters and even made sure the modules all mirrored each other and it still doesn't work on my local server

Comment: Nevermind, it randomly started working after making a new lesson but it didn't work on the first lesson I created. Thank you so much for all the effort you put in!

Comment: in your view's contextual filter, did you click the "MORE" button and check mark the Allow multiple values

Comment: Yeah, I got that, not sure what happened with the first lesson but it's all working now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24371/discussion-between-no-sssweat-and-chris3spice).